# My if-else loop keeps repeating for my assembly code

Tags: assembly, keil

```
   __main

    MOV R0, #0 
    MOV R1, #0

    MOV R0, #1 

    CMP R0, #1
    BEQ goToIf
    BNE goToElse
    MOV R0, #6
    MOV R1, #7
    B goToConditionalInstructions

    goToIf
        MOV R0, #2 
        MOV R1, #4


    goToElse
        MOV R0, #3
        MOV R1, #5

    goToConditionalInstructions

    CMP R1, #7
    MOVEQ R0, #8
    MOVEQ R1, #10
    MOVNE R0, #9
    MOVNE R1, #11

loop
    CMP R0, #14
    ADDLE R0, R0, #1
    BLE loop

loop2
    SUBS R0, R0, #5
    BGT loop2

stop B stop

    END
```

Hi, this is a code for my lab project where we have to use loops, while loops and if-else. For some reason when I am running my if-else loop after going to **if** the code runs **else** as well. I am not sure if I am missing something because I am new to this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a branch statement at the end of the `IF` section, just before the `goToElse` label, to jump over the `ELSE` section.

Comment: and how can I accomplish this? They did teach us to make the code more efficient with less code and just putting the **else** part, but I would like to know how to implement both **if** and **else** for future reference.

Comment: @Prophed Scott gave you exactly what you need. You need to jump over the `else` code branch... therefore after your two `mov` instructions in your `goToIf` label, you need a `jmp endIf` ... and you need to place an `endif:` label after the `goToElse` instructions. Think of it like this: your `goToIf` executes code... but never stops running code. Therefore execution just drops into the `goToElse` code. If you add a jump to jump over the else... it will work as expected.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Not clear that this particular language has a `jmp` instruction, but (because its in the posted code) it does have a `B`.